# How to display the item below my logo?

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to display the border below of my logo. But I don't know how to do it. I tried to experiment but it seems not working on my side. Below is the code that I'm using on my project website. Your answer is highly appreciated.

```css
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

div .logopix {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 7rem;
  clear: both;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  border: 2rem red solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Poppins|Roboto|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>HUB Motivator</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logopix" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="HUB Motivator Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="menu"></div>
  </header>
  <main></main>
  <!-- <footer>&copy; Copyright 2018</footer> -->
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of `position:absolute` in your logo image css...absolute positioned elements are removed from the normal document flow, thats why its not taking any space in your DOM...

So remove absolute position and put `text-align:center` in your `logo` class to center the image...

```css
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  border: 2rem red solid;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img class="logopix" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="HUB Motivator Logo">
  </div>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</header>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Positions in your css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Poppins|Roboto|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>HUB Motivator</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
    <center>
      <div class="logo">
        <img class="logopix" src="./images/logo.png" alt="HUB Motivator Logo" >
      </div>
     </center>
      <div class="menu">

      </div>

    </header>

    <main>


    </main>


    <!-- <footer>&copy; Copyright 2018</footer> -->

  </body>
</html>
```

in CSS

```
.logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
 }

 div .logopix {
   margin: 0;
   height: 7rem;
   clear: both;
   }

.menu {
  display: block;
  border: 2rem red solid;
}
```

Here id the Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j0p3ueym/3/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/6jm2qga3/19/) is the JSfiddle

I've used "after" and added the following code

```
div:after {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 10px;
background-color:red;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left bottom;
}
```